# How do I bind a skeleton to a mesh?

Tags: c#, wpf, mesh, sharpdx, helix-3d-toolkit

I need to create a mesh and its skeleton with data that is already present as raw data (Vertices, Indices, TextureCoordinates, Normals, Bones, Weights, Positions, and so on). I have a `MeshGeometryModel3D` fully setup and it works perfectly with the Helix Toolkit SharpDX in WPF. It currently represents a character without its skeleton / animations. Now, I want to attach a skeleton to it. I just don't find any documentation to do so. I looked at the examples but the only interesting thing I found, was the "BoneSkin" Example, but it's loading a fbx file without doing it with raw data.

I think atleast, that I need something other than a `MeshGeometryModel3D`, because it is missing any bone bindings so I found `BoneSkinnedMeshGeometry3D` but it seems to be missing important features like "Materials".

I tried:

- Setup a fully working `MeshGeometryModel3D`, but seems to be incompatible with bones
- I tried using the `BoneSkinnedMeshGeometry3D` class but it seems to be missing important features like Materials and I'm not sure how to use this class, because I don't find any documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `BoneSkinMeshGeometryModel3D` with `BoneSkinMeshGeometry3D`.

Comment: Do you mind explaining me, how i can use those classes to implement my own skeleton? Or even better: Can you provide me with topics to learn, so that i can understand it myself?

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Real-Time-Rendering-Fourth-Tomas-Akenine-M%C3%B6ller/dp/1138627003
Vertex Blending chapter.

Comment: Basically you want to define an array of transform matrix, then assign bone index on each vertex to associate with 1~4 transform matrix in the array. Then updating the array of transform matrix in each frame to do the bone-skinned animation.